# What chips does a Sony Ericsson (feature phone) use? (e.g. K510i, K610i, W705, C510)

Tags: cellphone, specifications, teensy

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of these awesome Sony Ericsson phones by using Teensy 3.6 so I'm wondering what kind of specifications and chips do these phones have.

The phones in question are: Sony Ericsson K510i, K610i, W705 and C510.

The chips I need to know about about are:

- The CPU: Is it a microcontroller or a CPU or a System-on-a-Chip? What is the architecture? What is the frequency? Does it execute or interpret Java bytecode? Does it have an MMU? What are its I/O functions? DMA, hardware M2 card I/O, audio DAC? Would such a CPU be stronger than the one in Teensy 3.6?
- The storage memory chip: What kind of a storage memory chip do these phones have? Is the storage embedded in the MCU/SoC?
- Where is the RAM contained? How much of it and what type of it? SRAM or SDRAM? Is it in the CPU/MCU/SoC or is it a separate chip?
- What encodes and decodes images, videos and music?
- Do the display and the camera have any encoding algorithms in hardware/firmware?

Does anyone have any information about these phones?

Comment: Addressing the entire function of a GSM phone in this forum and format is far too broad.

Answer (score 1):

There's a website called ifixit that does "teardowns" of phones that may be of interest to you; or you could do it yourself by dismantling a phone and looking at the chips. [Here's an excellent example by Bunnie Huang](https://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?page_id=3107).

You will face 3 major problems:

- the radio software is far too large for one person to write (although some of the SDR-GSM people have got most of the way, and it's all specified in 3GPP).
- you need approval from your local telecoms regulator to use the phone if you've built it yourself
- many of the cheap chipsets used simply aren't sold to the public. You'll have to get yourself a good Mandarin interpreter and buy them under the counter at Shenzen. The documentation (if any) will also probably be in Mandarin.

Video and audio decoding will nearly always be hardware-accelerated. Storage is usually DRAM and Flash. Either separate or "chip-on-chip" like the Pi.